# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=*;begin select ;(, DRIVER=4.19.26

Tags: sql, validation, db2, connection, wildfly

I am relatively new to DB2 but not to SQL. I am experiencing the below error when trying a SELECT statement

```
<validation>
   <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
   <background-validation>true</background-validation>
   <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
   <check-valid-connection-sql>begin; select * from DBSCHEMA.DB_VALIDITY_CHECK where CHECKER = 1 for update; commit;</check-valid-connection-sql>
```

can someone help me

tried to change the sql:

1. begin select * from DBSCHEMA.DB_VALIDITY_CHECK where CHECKER = 1 for update with rs; commit;
2. begin select * from DBSCHEMA.DB_VALIDITY_CHECK where CHECKER = 1 for update; commit; end;

the exact error is: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=*;begin select ;(, DRIVER=4.19.26

Comment: You can't use "SELECT INTO NOWHERE" in the compound statements. It should be something like this: `begin declare v1 int; select count (1) into v1 from DBSCHEMA.DB_VALIDITY_CHECK where checker=1 with rs use and keep update locks; end`. BTW, why to commit just after placing locks on the table which effectively means removing these locks?

Comment: @Mark Barinstein The validation check locks the database with the FOR UPDATE clause, which ensures that the current transaction is the only one that can modify the data until it is committed. The COMMIT statement at the end of the SQL code finalizes the transaction and releases the lock on the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "SELECT INTO NOWHERE" in the compound statements.
It should be something like this:

```
begin 
  declare v1 int;

  select count (1) into v1 
  from DBSCHEMA_DB_VALIDITY_CHECK 
  where checker=1 
  with rs use and keep update locks;

  -- your code is here
  -- ...

  commit;
end
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fBiDMMum)

Comment: This worked for me, but i need to lock it somehow: SELECT 1 FROM DBSCHEMA.DB_CONN_VALIDITY_CHECK WHERE CHECKER = 1 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY FOR UPDATE

Comment: this should be check-connection-valid for the standalone.xml in wildfly. But with this idea wildfly immediately has a problem

Comment: The statement I've provided places U locks on all qualified table rows until the end of transaction. What's the exact problem with it in your environment? What does it mean -  "check-connection-valid"?